# How to do sync with local database and parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-sqlite

I have an Android application where the app should work offline. In the app when the records are been created during offline mode they are stored in the local database(sqlite), when the internet connection is available the records that were been created during offline should sync with parse.

How can I do it in Android?

Comment: Parse has saveInBackgroud method, you may use it when user is offline.

Answer (score 1):

Simple while run a background service to check whether your mobile is connected to internet or not,then
get the data from your Local Database in one list and then Parse data into other list

```
public Collection nonOverLap(Collection coll1, Collection coll2) {
   Collection result = union(coll1, coll2);
   result.removeAll(intersect(coll1, coll2));
   return result;
} // will return elements missing in parse
```

Then update the nonOverlap into parse Db :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into firebase or couchdb or parse data objects

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects

https://www.firebase.com/

http://www.couchbase.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check if device is connected to the Internet:

```
public static boolean isDeviceConnectedToTheInternet(Context ctx) {

    NetworkInfo networkInfo =
            ((ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Then choose a scenario.

Comment: The thing is after saving data in the parse from local database, again I have to fetch the same data from parse that have objectId's.