# Distinguishing Users in SQL database - sync with multiple SQLite offline databases C# UWP

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, tomcat, uwp

I opened a thread here:
[SQLite Database vs online database C# UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253333/sqlite-database-vs-online-database-c-sharp-uwp?noredirect=1#comment87527082_50253333)

but I have a second, more general question that was not answered:

How do I distinguish data of each user from all the others after sync between multiple SQLite files and one SQL server?

I mean, since the SQLite is offline and local db solution, I did not implement any user/password thing.

But since multiple users will be syncing between their Host and Client app via SQL temporary database, I don't know what is the usual technique to achieve this.

**My theory** is to force host app user for user/password creation and store that data in one of the SQLite tables locally. Then, I should use [SQLite-Sync](http://github.com/sqlite-sync/SQLite-sync.com)
to pull all current users' data from SQLite and combine it with his specific user credentials.

But, since I never used SQL (only SQLite) I don't know how user management works. **Here is my question then**:

How do I separate each users' data from the others?

Is the user assigned to each row of data like an additional field in order to distinguish specific users' data?

Or is there a separate table for each user? Or maybe there are different databases for each user? (sorry if my theories are too nooby).

**EDIT:**
I just had another idea, maybe it is possible to avoid SQL server mediation if I manage to parse user SQLite data directly between the two apps? Something like this: [How to do sync with local database and parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796625/how-to-do-sync-with-local-database-and-parse)
 but in UWP vs Android.

Comment: What is the scope of the data here? Every user has their on set of data and only they should/are allowed to work with that? Or is some of the data somehow shared between users (read only or read/write)? What is the purpose of the database server? And which DBMS do you use the database server? Please try to describe you scenario and your requirements in greater detail.

Comment: each user will have their data and should be allowed to see/use only that data. For server I did not decide yet. The purpose of the server is that data of UWP SQLite must be transfered to SQLite of Android device.

Comment: Then I'd think about having a database and a login for each user (_n_ databases and _n_  logins, if there are _n_ users). A login only gets rights on the respective database. Then it's clear whats who's. Of course you'll have the overhead to create a new database and login for each user but I think, that's easier than adding a new column to every table to indicate which user's row that is. Or juggling with multiple tables. Should be the safest approach too, as I'd consider the barrier to trick the server is quite high.

Comment: any drawbacks like number of databases limit on SQL side?

Comment: In general no. In detail, that depends on the actual system (version, flavor, environment...).